# Can't replace string content in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have values from submission that I appended into a data frame that look like the following:

```
df['SalePrice'] = submission

0       [381659.34]
1       [639894.75]
2       [189159.39]
3       [203588.45]
4       [609621.25]
```

I tried to remove the brackets from each side of the float with this code:

```
df['SalePrice'] = df.SalePrice.replace("[","").replace("]","")  
print(df['SalePrice'])
```

I am not able to remove the brackets.  Is there any way to clean-up this float in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try flattening the list before you put it into the dataframe:

```
submission_flat = [item for sublist in submission for item in sublist]
df['SalePrice'] = submission_flat
```

Comment: That worked:  submission_flat = [item for sublist in submission for item in sublist]
df['SalePrice'] = submission_flat
df['SalePrice'] = round(df['SalePrice'],2)

Answer (score 4):

Try str and strip:

```
df.SalePrice.str.strip('[]')
```

Comment: When I ran df.SalePrice.str.strip('[]'), the whole content is erased and  I get NaN as an answer

Comment: That is odd. I tried with the data you provided and it worked. can you try if `df.SalePrice.str.replace('[','')` works?

Comment: This is my code block:
submission = [];
for ele in regressor.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test, shuffle=False, batch_size=32)):
  submission.append(np.expm1(ele['predictions']))
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Id', 'SalePrice']);
df['Id'] = df_test['Id'];
df['SalePrice'] = submission;
df['SalePrice'] = df.SalePrice.str.replace('[','');
print(df['SalePrice']);
I get NaN as an answer

Comment: can you try `type(df['SalePrice'][0])`

Comment: here is the result: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: so that means that the parentheses are a result of the data being an array, and not a string. My answer should work for strings, @PythononToast 's answer works for your problem.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I will remember your version for a string, in the future.